# how to deploy my maven project for devops pipeline

Tags: maven, jenkins, deployment, devops

I have an devops project assignment that I am required to create a maven project and also create a CI/CD pipeline for it. I am quiet newbie in devops and struggling to understand some concepts.

I created a maven project and pushed it into bitbucket. By the way, I have 3 main branches which are master, test and development that I need to deploy them prod, qa and dev environments, respectively. Via Jenkins, I successfully created build automation.

However, I could not deploy the project because I am confused. Can I also deploy my project with Jenkins? Or do I need a something like Virtualbox to deploy? Also do I have to use Docker to deploy? I searched for web but could not make it clear.

Could you please help me understand the deployment process in this project?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "deploy the project"? Is it a war that you deploy on an application server?

Comment: @JFMeier by saying "deploy the project", I mean the phase after build..I guess it refers to continuous deployment part. I do not have any war file yet. Do I need to create it first?

Comment: Why do you need to guess? If you don't know for what purpose it should be deployed you need to ask your boss first.

Comment: @JFMeier Sorry for not mentioning it is a course project. I am a newbie in this area and trying to understand concepts, that is why I say "I guess".. It should be deployed due to the step of continuous deployment of the project assignment that we are required to create a CI/CD pipeline. Is it clearer now? Do you have any recommendation?

Comment: No, then please ask the instructor of the course what kind of deployment he/she expects.

Comment: Teacher gives no clue that is why I am asking it here.

Comment: So what kind of project is it? Is it a WAR that should run on Tomcat or JBoss? Is it Spring boot? What is it?

Comment: Actually, I made some progress. With the help of Cloudbee Docker BUild and Publish plugin, I could built the project and also started deploying. In deploy phase, although I added crendentials for docker hub in Jenkins, it failed by saying authentication requires while pushing into Dockerhub. It is strange because from cmd I can see Docker image is created and I can manuelly push into Dockerhub. However, it seem somehow Jenkins cannot handle authentication issue. In crendential part, I added my Dockerhub username and password in Jenkins. However, Jenkins says this is not used.

Comment: @JFMeier Since the problem has changed, I created another question yesterday. You can see the log in there:
 https://stackoverflow.com/q/62205973/10580552
Do you have any idea how to fix this credential problem?

Answer (score 0):

Deployment processes are depends on your infrastructure. What do you use?

There are tons of deployment strategies according to business/development models. You can deploy your projects with Jenkins or any CI/CD tools that you chose. It doesn't matter at the end.

Here it's a good deployment strategies reading by Google.
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/application-deployment-and-testing-strategies

Comment: As I stated in the question, I use Jenkins. I created multi-branch pipeline in Jenkins and succesfully built. Now I want to deploy the project but I am not sure how to do that.. Is it possible in Jenkins? By the way, thanks for the link. I will check it out immediately. @zenka

Comment: Yes it's possible in Jenkins. Jenkins is one of the most popular CI/CD tools.